# Delaying a program in python with string as an argument

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to make a program which includes taking input from user and using that input to delay the program but I can't figure out how to use that input because Time.sleep() take only int or float as arguments but I need a function which delays the program like time.sleep() but take string as an arguments.

Here is the program:Now the input given by user is stored in t variable so I need some function which can take t as an argument.

```
import webbrowser
import time

print "This is the take a break program"
t= raw_input("In how much time will you take a break? \n")
print ("%s,seconds"%t)
time.sleep(t)
webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a string to int/float in python, simply do:

```
#Let say this is your String
String mystring = "100"

#This will convert your string to int
int time = int(mystring)

#And this will convert it to a float
float timeFloat = float(mystring)
```

Remember to check your user input as it won't work as expected if the string is composed of letters only.